# What is the circular pavement at the end of a runway called?

Tags: airport, runways, airport-design

What is the circular pavement at the end of a runway called where aircraft turn 180 degrees to then backtrack? Is the term runway turning bay appropriate for that?

The problem is that there is a special NOTAM at our aerodrome for big aicraft (more than 75 tons of weight) to turn not on the runway but only in this adjacent part, and with maximum radius due to fragile asphault pavement.

Comment: Are you referring to a [turn pad](https://caasref.wordpress.com/runway-turn-pad-making/)?

Comment: The fact is I'm from Russia. And the term is not used in any official documents. And sometimes our controllers have misunderstanding with the pilots isung this term while giving instructions for RW vacation. Is it used world wide?

Comment: ATC will rarely refer to this term. They will just advice the pilot to "backtrack"

Comment: Yes, I know it. But still the problem exists. Some pilots do no follow that NOTAM causing much problems to the aerodrome service while repairing asphault after the landing especially in hot weather. Anyway the controller is not responsible for the RW conditions and he is not to blame.

Comment: That’s what it’s called in the [Eurocontrol Controller Lexicon](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Runway_Turn_Pad) and in FAA NOTAMs in the US.

Answer (score 3):

It is called the **turn pad**. This area(pad) is usually located at the thresholds of the runway, where no taxiway exists, so in order for the pilots to make a full-length takeoff, (or taxi to the Apron) they have to backtrack amd make a U-turn on there. Gernerally speaking, these pads exist on small airports. [You can see the turn pads at the 2 thresholds of the runway. Skiathos Airport, Greece](https://skopelosnews.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/skiathos-whole-2.jpg)
[Source](https://ext.eurocontrol.int/lexicon/index.php/Runway_Turn_Pad)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Our airport is small indeed)